# Pip not working for Python3.4

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

`pip` is not working. Whenever I try to install a package, the command line stops working but doesn't show any error. I tried pressing CTRL+Z but this also didn't show a response. Below is screenshot:

[image: no response of pip install]
P.S. `pip` command shows the list of commands and general options.

Comment: When you enter ```pip install pillow``` nothing shows up?

Comment: yes. it shows nothing @Vahid Msm

Comment: What does `dir pip*` say?

Comment: It shows "file not found". But if I go to Python34\Scripts folder and type dir pip*, it shows me list of files

Comment: Does calling with the full path: `...Python34\Scripts\pip` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. By disabling the AVAST shields I am able to install packages by pip. @Mike Muller @Vahid Msm